# VS nugget installed but not able to use

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

I cloned a project and reinstalled nuggets via:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

This returned success, references are added as well, but when I try to use it by `using blahblah` I get:

"The type or namespace 'package_name' could not been found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help is welcome.

Comment: First of all its `NuGet`, second - can you see the added libraries in your references list?

Comment: clean and re-build

Comment: first thing I've done - thanks